# Why does Barbara refer to Sheba with an "S" at times when writing in her diary?

Tags: plot-explanation, notes-on-a-scandal

In [*Notes on a Scandal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465551/), Barbara is continuously writing in her diary throughout the film while it is being narrated by her character.

Barbara is writing about Sheba for the majority of the film and refers to her by her full name most of the time.  There are a few times where Barbara refers to Sheba as "S":

> "S"and I share the ability...to see through the quotidian awfulness of
>   things.

Another entry later in the film:

> I long to phone "S,"but it's late. Poor girl. All alone with her awful
>   family.

Barbara has no reservations about naming Sheba in her diary writings in her other entries.  Barbara is very meticulous about writing in her diary.  She makes daily entries in it and explains her innermost thoughts and desires.

**So, why does she refer to Sheba as "S" in these two entries?**